# Get notified of Facebook Page activity?

Tags: facebook, rss

Is it possible to get notified by email or RSS of new activity in your Facebook Page?

Comment: What kind of activity ? Just comments and postings ?

Comment: @phwd Yes. (15 characters)

Comment: I get a weekly update of activity on pages I created, but is that too high level for you?

Comment: @glasnt Yes, too high level and too late.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the rss feed of a page from http://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?format=atom10&id=xxxxx . It includes any post to your page but sadly not the comments.

Comment: This seems to be the best option so far. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

They used to have that option, but not anymore. At least not for what you are asking for.

Comment: So technically the only way to find out about new activity is to visit/reload the page?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "At least not what you are asking for."?

Comment: @rchern They have some feeds but not for the news feed activity.

Answer (score 0):

You can enter the Facebook RSS at [FeedPostal.com](http://www.feedpostal.com) and it will send you updates daily, weekly or monthly depending on your settings.

Answer (score -1):

certainly by email. Log in to FB > Account > Account Settings > Notifications tab
has a long list of different things you can be notified about via email or SMS...
among which the "Wall Comments" category might cover what you want?

unless, of course, I am not understanding the question. HTH

Comment: not a Facebook Profile. A Facebook *Page*

Comment: I see - thanks for the clarification.. the question was about "your Facebook Page" - thought [s]he meant activity on your own wall, but I see now that 'Page' was a keyword.